# Flatsome theme, show sidebar without clicking on mobile product page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, click

I have a quick question about the theme’s product pages on mobile. How can I show the sidebar below the content. I know how to show the sidebar by using the ”filter” button but I need to show it without having to click.

I looked at the event on the filter button but it is a minified function inside flatsome.js?ver=3.12.1
but didn't figure out how to call the funcion.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

From the WP dashboard, go to Appearance > Customize > WooCommerce > Product Page and uncheck the option that says "Off-canvas Sidebar for Mobile."

[screenshot of Customizer option described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMQaz.png)

This should place the sidebar below the product page content on mobile.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that I still have to click on FILTER to show the sidebar with the catergories, I need to show the sidebar as soon as the product page loads.

Comment: If the box is UNchecked, the sidebar should load below the product content (gallery, title, description, attributes, etc.) and not require you to click "Filter."

Have you cleared the server cache to make sure it's displaying the change?